# WCF using webHttpBinding - how to take parameters?

Tags: c#, wcf, post

I have a simple wcf method called '`test`' (the wcf service is configured for `webHttpBinding`)

I can make an HTTP POST to it fine without parameters, however I want to send it just a string as a single parameter but cant seem to achieve this?

For instance, the method `test(string s){};`

I have tried posting to `test` with the data `'hello world'` and `'&s=hello world'` to no avail.

Edit: The interface for `test` looks something like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "test", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string test(string s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `test(string s)` to `test(Stream s)` fixed this.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to post this as part of your request body:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Hello World</string>
```

You can try it from fiddler. Or if you want to post from a .NET CLient use the below code@

```
var client = new RestClient();  
client.BaseUrl = serviceBaseUrl;  
var request = new RestRequest(method){RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml};      
request.Resource = resourceUrl;  
request.AddParameter("text/xml", requestBody,  ParameterType.RequestBody);  
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

You need to download the API called RestSharp for the above code to work

Comment: I dont think its necessary to download any third party APIs for this?

Comment: @maxp: I said for using the code posted above you would need RestSharp. I never said its mandatory.